# Random charges of tyranny

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I recently acquired an opinion penalty of tyranny for reasons unknown. The only two things I can think of:

1. I decided to righteously imprison someone via the popup, then somehow by the time the action was carried out the righteousness was invalidated, which should be impossible as imprisonment is instant. Maybe I opened the popup and by the time I clicked "Imprison" they had their plot auto-stopped.
2. I have all my vassal levies raised for more than -40 opinion. Every single vassal with the tyranny penalty also has a -40+ opinion penalty for raised levies and the tyranny penalty appeared at roughly the same time the levies penalty went past -40, but this isn't listed on the wiki as being tyrannous.

Are either of these possibilities and is there a way in the console to examine the tyranny penalty (to at least determine when it occurred).

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe I opened the popup and by the time I clicked "Imprison" they had
>   their plot auto-stopped.

That's precisely what happened. It is not impossible, it has happened to me many times.

As evident from your statement, you have auto-stop plots option enabled. So what happens is:

1. A vassal plots something.
2. You get a popup to imprison them.
3. Meanwhile, a message is on its way to the vassal to end their plot.
4. The time it takes for a landed noble to respond to a missive depends on the distance it is from your capital.
5. By the time you clicked imprison, the vassal had already ended their plot. Which therefore gave you a tyranny penalty as you imprisoned them without a cause.

An important thing to note is, whenever the plot is autostopped and you have imprison dialogue open, it immediately shows that you will get -40 penalty. I reckon you did not notice that and imprisoned the guy anyways.

There is no console command available in this regard except the remotely related neg_opinion command. You can view [list of all console commands here](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Console_commands).